# What parameters have to converge before doing a relax calculation?

Tags: quantum-espresso, cell-optimization

I am a beginner of Quantum Espresso. I have taken 221 MoS2 Monolayer and done a relax calculation.
In case of bulk system, or any doping in supercell, which is preferred: `vc-relax` or `relax`?
It's not clear to me under what conditions I need to use one vs the other.

Before the relax calculation, I converged ecutwfc, k-points and ecutrho (using ultrasoft pseudopotential). Do any other parameters have to converge before starting this type of calculation?

Comment: This is your answer for first part  https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2358/when-should-vc-relax-be-performed-over-relax-calculations-in-quantum-espress   For relaxed structure energy and energetics of doping, convergence of  K-point, ecutwfc, ecutrho is sufficient

Comment: Thankyou for the answer

Answer (score 3):

Prior to any production calculation, the convergence study with `ecutwfc`, `k-points` and `ecutrho` should be enough. But, the better should be to do a convergence study using the property you are interested in.

Please, take a look in previous discussion [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/500/24), [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/316/24) and [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/317/24).